# como cargar contenido en ajax al enviar un formulario

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

estoy usando laravel y tengo un formulario que al enviarse quiero que cargue contenido con ajax y que se matenga parte de mi pagina y no me redireccione directamente a la ruta que tiene el action, trate de hacerlo como otras funciones de click que ya tenia pero solo me bota el json de mi controlador al enviar el formulario

```
<div class="card">
<h5 class="card-header">Agregar Region</h5>
<div class="card-body">
    <p class="cart-text">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <form id="formulario-agregar-region" action="{{route('Rstore')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <label for="">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form control" required>
                <br></br>
                <label for="">Descripcion</label>
                <input type="text" name="descripcion" class="form control" value="...">
                <br></br>
                <label for="">Otros</label>
                <input type="text" name="otros" class="form control" value="...">
                <br></br>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-info" id="volver-index" data-url-Avolver="{{route('regiones')}}">
                    <span class="fa fa-solid fa-undo-alt"></span>Regresar</a>
                <button id="agregar-region-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar
                    <span class="fa fa-solid fa-user-plus"></span>
                </button>
                
            </form>
            
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
```

'en mi js tengo `

```
contenidoDinamico.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (event.target.id === "agregar-region-btn") {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        fetch(this.action, {
            method: this.method,
            body: new FormData(this)
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            
            contenidoDinamico.innerHTML = data;
            
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error:", error);
        });
    }
});
```

contenido dimamico es una variable que modifca un div en mi pagina princial`

Comment: Que hay en `contenidoDinamico`? Probablemente te falte un `preventDefault` para que el formulario no se envíe por default y solo ejecute ese js https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: solo hay obtengo el id de un div     :  var contenidoDinamico = document.getElementById("contenido-dinamico");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
// Selecciona el formulario y el botón por sus id 
const formulario = document.getElementById('formulario-agregar-region')
const btnSubmit = document.getElementById('agregar-region-btn')

// Escucha el evento click a traves de tu boton Agregar
btnSubmit.addEventListener('click', async e => {
    e.preventDefault(); // Cancela el evento por Default

    const formData = new FormData(formulario); // Formulario

    const url = `ruta`; // Aquí va la ruta a donde vas a hacer la petición por ejemplo lo que tienes en action="{{route('Rstore')}}"

    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        });

        const data = await response.json();
        if (!response.ok) {
            // Si no hubo éxito
            console.log(response)
        } else {
            // Si hubo éxito en la petición 
            console.log(response)
        }

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e); // Si se produce una excepción
    }
})
```

Verifica que tu ruta en Laravel sea del tipo post en el archivo web.php:

```
Route::post('/nombreDeTuRuta', [TuController::class, 'store']);
```

pdt: Este @csrf no lo vayas quitar de tu html ya que este contiene el Token necesario para hacer la petición y se agrega automáticamente al formulario al declarar el formData en JS.

Espero que te sirva, Saludos!

Comment: gracias agrege las variables url y el formData y lo adapte a mi propia estructura de ajax que ya tenia y funciono